# Date() in js doesn't switch days correctly

Tags: javascript, date

I want to increase and decrease days in a date without changing other parts of the date. For example, when I have:

- 31 December 2021 -> add one day -> 01 December 2021, **or**
- 01 December 2021 -> subtract one day -> 31 December 2021

Below, is my increase day code. It works fine and I get what I want:

```
let cur_date = new Date();

setInterval(() => {
  let curMonth = cur_date.getMonth();
  cur_date.setDate(cur_date.getDate() + 1);
  if (cur_date.getMonth() !== curMonth) {
    cur_date.setMonth(curMonth);
  }
  console.log(cur_date.toLocaleString());
}, 1000);
```

My decrease day code does not work and I get `31 December 2021` after `01 November 2021`:

```
let cur_date = new Date();

setInterval(() => {
  let curMonth = cur_date.getMonth();
  cur_date.setDate(cur_date.getDate() - 1);
  if (cur_date.getMonth() !== curMonth) {
    cur_date.setMonth(curMonth);
  }
  console.log(cur_date.toLocaleString());
}, 1000);
```

How to fix it?

Comment: That's because November does not have 31 days, like October has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because November does not have 31 days, and so when you go one day back from 1 November, you get 31 October. Then you change the month so it would be 31 November, but JavaScript interprets that as 30 November + 1 day = 1 December.

To avoid this, perform a check *before* subtracting one day: if the date is 1, then first add a month, and then let the subtraction of 1 day happen:

```js
let cur_date = new Date();

setInterval(() => {
  let curMonth = cur_date.getMonth();
  if (cur_date.getDate() === 1) { // Do the check here, before subtracting 1 day
    cur_date.setMonth(curMonth + 1); // Go temporary to next month
  }
  cur_date.setDate(cur_date.getDate() - 1);
  console.log(cur_date.toLocaleString());
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful to me.

Comment: You'll need to do that check in a loop for 1st February -> 31st January -> 3rd March

Comment: Almost forget about marking)) Thanks.

Comment: @phuzi, no, there is no need for a loop. Did you check? This solution does not go from 1st February to 31st January. Please read again.

Comment: Fair enough, like your solution better 